# How do I play VALORANT on a non-Intel, Apple silicon Mac computer?

Tags: macos, valorant

*VALORANT*, currently, is not on MacOS. It is also not on Steam. You cannot download *VALORANT* through the website because... Well, there's no button to do so. So how do you get it on Mac?

Originally, I thought about using Mac's built-in Bootcamp partition, but that doesn't work, because the Mac is a 2021 M1 MacBook Air (meaning not Intel-based, dubbed 'Apple silicon' instead).

I found out that, apparently, you can do this:

> M1 mac doesn't support boot camp and it will never support bootcamp.
> Apple silicon Mac have a new Start Up options feature. You can install
> any OS you want on it and do multi boot. There are no restriction from
> Apple.
> -https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253556967?answerId=257171239022#257171239022 (ShunnyBunny)

If that's true, how do you do this?

Assuming you can't do that, are there any other ways to get it? Maybe another Windows emulator?

Comment: Relevant [meta] post about this question: [Why was this question about running Valorant on macOS downvoted?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17064/4797)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't play Valorant on a Mac as it is not supported.

1. The kernel-level anti-cheat, *Vangard* only runs on Windows.
2. *Vangard* is configured to block Virtual Machines, which is the only environment on which Windows can run on an Apple Silicon Mac.

Many guides will say it is possible, but this is through Bootcamp (think: dual-booting Windows and Mac) and an intel-based x64 CPU, which are only in Macs older than 2021.

Furthermore, **it is currently impossible to properly license or obtain Windows 11 for ARM for dual-booting** (dual booting in itself is a whole other can of worms) due to license agreements with Parallels.

Any and all guides that gets around this restriction will get your account banned for "cheating".

[Read More](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/options-for-using-windows-11-with-mac-computers-with-apple-m1-m2-and-m3-chips-cd15fd62-9b34-4b78-b0bc-121baa3c568c)